# Do non-linear passive pneumatic throttles exist?

Tags: pneumatic

On of the more simple throttles is a channel, which is described by the [Hagen-Poiseuille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation) equation:
$$\Delta P = \frac{8\mu L Q}{\pi r^4}$$
This equation, when rearranged, tells us that the Flowrate $Q$ is linearly dependent on $\Delta P$. Do passive non-linear pneumatic devices exist, which are not linearly dependent on $\Delta P$?

For example, is there a pneumatic equivalent to the [Thermistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor) - which has a non-constant $R(U)$-dependency, and as such a nonlinear Flow vs Voltage curve?

Comment: Well, above the Reynolds number, you'll go nonlinear, but probably not in a useful way.    More to the point: can you post the problem you're trying to solve, rather than asking how to design the solution  you've posited?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft In the application of interest, I want an approximate constant flowrate for a certain pressure range (e.g. 1-5 bar) through a device. I know there are devices that can accomplish that, but there are other constraints which wont allow me to use them. I think my question is a little too broad, I will rephrase it to be more specific.

Comment: When you rephrase the question, also include the solutions that won't work for you

Comment: Give this link a look, might answer your question. If not, rephrase the question to look something like in this link: (http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/estimating-maximum-speed-for-a-pneumatic-cylinder)

Comment: Well there is choked flow: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choked_flow

Comment: Well, a typical [pressure regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_regulator) is entirely mechanical and produces constant output pressure for allowed range of input pressures; with constant output gas consumption you obtain constant flow.

Comment: There are some peculiar fluidics devices that can do this by stacking a series of small vortex units, but only on micro scale. Above tiny scales, the lack of efficiency usually starts to be an issue with more passive approaches. Note that you have to balance the energy equation, so a passive device has to be supplied with excess energy and must absorb all the unwanted energy somehow. Turbulent friction is the usual first suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Take [Tesla airflow check valve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_valve).

[image]

In the 'pass' direction it's very much linear per  Hagen-Poiseuille equation. In the reverse direction for tiny $\Delta P$ it's linear, but as the pressure increases, the flow increase is vanishingly low. I'm not sure what the exact relation is in the inverse direction, but it's way far from linear - and the device is entirely passive, no moving parts whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

certainly. the most common example is the pressure/flow regulator in a drip irrigation system. It uses a thick rubber disc with a little hole through its center. Pressurized water hits the disc and flows through the hole in it towards the drip heads. But that pressure also deforms the rubber disc in such a way as to squeeze down the hole's diameter, choking off the flow through it. With cleverness, you can design the rubber disc so as to automatically furnish, say, a constant 5 gallons per hour over a range of water system pressures varying from 20 to 80 PSI- a very neat trick, eh?

Answer (score 0):

So you want a valve that, once set for a particular flow rate, gives the same flow rate for a variety of differential pressures? If so, I think the only thing you're going to get to do that is a [constant flow valve](http://asahi-america.com/valves-and-actuation/manual-valves/constant-flow-valves). They're analog, but not exactly passive.

Answer (score 0):

orifices can be characterized by a quadratic P/Q characteristic (for a portion of the flow range)

cubic P/Q characteristic, (again for a portion of the flow range) can be constructed. It would need the added element of circulation of the fluid. For example in a disc shaped cavity, with the inlet coming in at the out side diameter and coming in tangentially to create the circulation. And the outlet in the center of the cavity. Thus the flow has to also overcome the centrifugal tendency to pass from the inlet to the outlet, which makes it "more difficult" than if the circulation were not present and it behaved as just an orifice. The cubic scaling doesn't meaningfully begin until fairly high flows, though.